# Python lambda function error when used with brackets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a pandas data frame with 'Datetime' column containing timestamp information, I want to extract the hour information from the 'Datetime' column and add it to the hour column of the data frame.

I am confused since my code works if I write the lambda function without the braces

```
df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

but, when I try this code instead

```
df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour**()**)
```

I get the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable".

On the other hand when I use split function with lambda expression, it works completely fine with the braces -

```
df['Reasons'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
```

Comment: hour is an int, not a function, split is a function

Comment: You should use `df['Datetime'].dt.hour`. You don't need to do `lambda x:` for everything. It is often better to just used the pandas method without it. Same for the split. You should do: `df['title'].str.split(':').str[0])` This is fundamental to writing good code with pandas, so it will greatly benefit you if you can keep these tips in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Dani Mesejo, hour is an attribute of the datetime object. Hence it is working fine without brackets. Once you add brackets, it assumes the hour is a function and so you are getting that error.

You can read more about datetime object in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour)